# Find the right usb port on mac using Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, serial-port

Using terminal :

```
 ls /dev/tty.*
```

will give me many addresses . My usb cable is connected to `Arduino UNO` board.

On the arduino IDE i see the port as : `/dev/cu.usbmodem1421(Arduino Uno)`  ,but when i am running the command on Terminal i get :

```
/dev/tty                             /dev/ttyr9             /dev/ttyu5
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port    /dev/ttyra              /dev/ttyu6
/dev/tty.Bluetooth-Modem            /dev/ttyrb              /dev/ttyu7
/dev/tty.usbmodem1421               /dev/ttyrc              /dev/ttyu8
/dev/ttyp0                         /dev/ttyrd               /dev/ttyu9
/dev/ttyp1                          /dev/ttyre              /dev/ttyua
```

That means i dont see the exact same port , as `.cu` , but as `.tty` .

None of the above would give me good result-means none of them is the right one? :

```
/dev/tty.usbmodem1421
/dev/cu.usbmodem1421
```

How would i know which of these is my real serial port ? i need to confirm that in some way .

Answer (score 0):

Well its working great if you just plug/unplug the port and see how it appears in the terminal . The right address was the one in the Terminal .